# Flashcards with Latex

Tags: flashcards

I have the following problem:

I would like to have a flashcard software in which I can write Latex formulas without to have installed Latex itself (Miktex etc) on my device. I suppose this is possible since XMind has also Latex integrated without having to install anything. As far as I could see Anki needs Latex to be installes? Any other options.

Further it would be cool to have this also on my mobile device.

Any suggestions?

Based on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flashcard_software

I see only Mnemosyne to be a solution but do I have to install Latex in this case?

Comment: Since you are explicitly asking for a LaTeX free solution, your question *has* to be considered off-topic here...

Comment: I don't, I ask for a solution that avoids installing all the stuff I usually need for Latex. What about Mathjax?

Comment: What about Overleaf?